# C# FileStream.BeginRead throws Win32 Error 1784 - The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation

Tags: c#, winapi, bluetooth, hid

**Context**:
I'm trying to create a Joy-Con Library for C# with the end goal of making it accessible to the Unity Community for prototyping Switch games.

**Details**: 
Joy-Cons use HID interface. After successfully enumerating the HID Devices using windows hid.dll bindings in C#, I get a valid device path and then attempt to make a FileStream object to communicate with the Joy-Con. Joy-Con report length used by other projects is 49 bytes. I successfully create the `FileStream`, but upon calling `stream.BeginRead();` I get an error "The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation". The only other context you should need to know is the HIDImports class provides the interface to WinHIDApi.

**Troubled Code**:

gist: https://gist.github.com/gjh33/3e05c2480a23755a61c67347ac72061b

```
    private void getFileStream()
    {
        SafeFileHandle deviceHandle = HIDImports.CreateFile(joycon.devicePath, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, HIDImports.EFileAttributes.Overlapped, IntPtr.Zero);

        // Get the attributes
        // See SimpleJoy search function for better explanations of this
        HIDImports.HIDD_ATTRIBUTES deviceAtts = new HIDImports.HIDD_ATTRIBUTES();
        deviceAtts.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceAtts);

        if (HIDImports.HidD_GetAttributes(deviceHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref deviceAtts))
        {
            if (deviceAtts.VendorID == Joycon.VENDOR_ID && (deviceAtts.ProductID == Joycon.LEFT_PRODUCT_ID || deviceAtts.ProductID == Joycon.RIGHT_PRODUCT_ID))
            {
                stream = new FileStream(deviceHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, Joycon.REPORT_LENGTH, true);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Attempted to communicate with a non joycon device");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went very wrong. When attemping to open filestream, HidD_GetAttributes failed");
        }
    }

    private void beginAsyncRead()
    {
        if (stream != null && stream.CanRead)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[Joycon.REPORT_LENGTH];
            Console.WriteLine("AttemptingRead");
            stream.BeginRead(buff, 0, Joycon.REPORT_LENGTH, new AsyncCallback(onRawReportReceived), buff);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I expect that the problem is that the handle you supply isn't that of a disk file.

Comment: The Wiimote Library project for c# uses this method. AFAIK it's ok to do this. Relevant code: https://github.com/BrianPeek/WiimoteLib/blob/master/WiimoteCS/WiimoteLib/Wiimote.cs#L229

Comment: Have you tried `FileStream.ReadAsync()` in place of the old `.BeginRead()` + Callback? Easier to handle, easier to debug.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I'm not familiar with c# IO so I wasn't aware `.BeginRead()` is considered old.